# In every weighted graph with every edges positive and more than $11$ vertices, there exist between every vertices at most $ 2n^{2} $ shortest paths

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to decide, whether the statement is true or not;

In every weighted graph with only positive edges and with at least 11 vertices, there exists at most $ 2n^{2} $ shortest paths between every two vertices, where n is the number of vertices.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to MathSE, what have you tried thinking about so far?

Comment: @OllyReynolds I drew some graphs, but I don't know how to decide if it applies to any graph with such parameters.

Answer (score 2):

False.

Consider the following graph on approximately $n$ vertices: $V(G) =$ $\{s\} +V_1 +V_2 + \ldots V_{\sqrt{n}} + \{t\}$, where

1. each $V_i$ has $\sqrt{n}$ vertices
2. there is an edge between every vertex in $V_i$ and every vertex in $V_{i+1}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots \sqrt{n}-1$, and between $s$ and every vertex in $V_1$, and between every vertex in $V_{\sqrt{n}}$ and $t$. [All edges have unit length]

There are at least $\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n}} >> 2 n^2$ shortest length paths from $s$ to $t$.

[If you require for every pair of vertices there to be an edge of finite positive length between them then for every pair of nonadjacent vertices in the graph as constructed above add an edge of length say $n$. This won't change the set of shortest paths.]

Comment: If you want to maximize the number of shortest paths - not that it's necessary for this problem - it's better to take $n/3$ sets of size $3$ (for $3^{n/3} \gg \sqrt n^{\sqrt n}$ paths). In general, $n/k$ sets of size $k$ will produce $(k^{1/k})^n$ paths, and $k^{1/k}$ is maximized when $k=e$, but with integers $k=3$ is best and $k=2$, $k=4$ are tied for second-best.